# Update Edit form list from SP-Update

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list

I have one project actually in production environment. I must deploy one change request on edit form of one list called Person.

I have developed one SharePoint Farm Solution with my list definition for all my list. Inside schema.xml of my list definition I have added this element inside  element:

```
<Form Type="EditForm" Url="PersonListEditForm.aspx" SetupPath="features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\Person_Template\PersonListEditForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
```

After that, I have published new WSP package and I have performed from SharePoint Management Shell this command:

```
Update-SPSolution -Identity MyProject.wsp -LiteralPath C:\MyProject.wsp -GACDeployment
```

Update process was executed successfully. I have disabled and enabled the feature with my list definition but my PersonListEditForm.aspx is not deployed.

Please, can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem is about the name space of ASP.NET page. ASP.NET page needs to have the same namespace of List definition.